# OnFling MotionEvent e1 null?

Tags: android

Ok. This thing almost drives me crazy.

Some days ago I could implement the code below and the toast was successfully called when I tried to swipe right or left.

However, now it can't be called, because the e1 is always null!

How could this happen? I try this code on the emulator, but a user reports me, that it also doesn't work on real device.

```
public class SwipeGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 100;

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
    private final Activity activity;
    protected MotionEvent mLastOnDownEvent = null;

    public SwipeGestureListener(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        mLastOnDownEvent = e;
        System.out.println(e);
        return super.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override   
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        System.out.println(e1 + " " + e2);
        if (e1==null)
            e1 = mLastOnDownEvent;
        if (e1==null || e2==null)
            return false;

        float dX = e2.getX()-e1.getX();
        float dY = e2.getY()-e1.getY();

        if (Math.abs(dY)<SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH && Math.abs(velocityX)>=SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(dX)>=SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE ) {

            if (dX>0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.fetchPrevious();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.fetchNext();
            }

            return true;
        } 

        return false;
    }

}
```

The code that implement the gesture:

```
final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(this, new SwipeGestureListener(this));
listview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
        }

});
```

Comment: can anyone give a proper solution for this?i'm also  facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and indeed it didn't work, then I changed the GestureDetector to the newer/updated API "GestureDetectorCompat" and changed a few further things: 
Used the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener instead of the OnSimpleGestureListener, 
onDown() should return true and then it worked. I can't explain it to you, what was the exact problem. But the change lines seemed to be problematic. Maybe someone can explain the underlying problem. Have a look at the code, which is working:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        final GestureDetectorCompat gdt = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new SwipeGestureListener(this));
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                }

        });

    }




    public class SwipeGestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{

        private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
        private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 100;

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
        private final Activity activity;
        protected MotionEvent mLastOnDownEvent = null;

        public SwipeGestureListener(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            mLastOnDownEvent = e;
            System.err.println("ondown");
            //System.out.println(e);
            return true;
        }

        @Override   
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            System.err.println("onFling");
            System.out.println(e1 + " " + e2);
            if (e1==null)
                e1 = mLastOnDownEvent;
            if (e1==null || e2==null)
                return false;

            float dX = e2.getX()-e1.getX();
            float dY = e2.getY()-e1.getY();

            if (Math.abs(dY)<SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH && Math.abs(velocityX)>=SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY && Math.abs(dX)>=SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE ) {

                if (dX>0) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // activity.fetchPrevious();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // activity.fetchNext();
                }

                return true;
            } 

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
    }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

       @Override
       public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return false;
       }

       }

   }
```

Please try it!

Comment: Sorry G_J, it's still the same. e1 still gives me null value

Comment: That's really strange. Did you try it with a different View (not ListView)? The code above works absolutely flawlessly, when I register an ImageView to the OnTouchListener! Could you show the rest of your code?

Comment: Yes I agree.. It works with the other view but not on one of my listview.. I will try to investigate the xml then.. Thanks for your help G_J

Comment: @G_J your idea is good but in my case, `onDown()` is never called, so I cannot intercept null value of e1. should `onDown()` be necessarily called when we swipe?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Make sure all your views have add the same `setOnTouchListener()` method. If your touch place is outside view you will get `null` on e1.

**My Example:**

```
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnSwipeTouchListener(mActivity) {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return super.onTouch(v, event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
        }
    };


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    mListView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);

    mAdapter = new OnlineAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, onTouchListener);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return v;

}
```

And my list adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // something

            mImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            mImage.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If there is a onclicklistener etc. which are swiping items, you should remove that listeners. Then it will work. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding a FrameLayout along with needed View (I was using a GridView, but think it can work with a ListView or other view)

GestureListener is the same as yours.
The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/colors_grid_panel"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@color/white"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/create_side_padding"
             android:paddingRight="@dimen/create_side_padding"
             android:visibility="gone">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/colors_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/stub"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In code:

```
colorsGrid.setOnTouchListener(onSwipeTouchListener);
stub.setOnTouchListener(onSwipeTouchListener);
```